# Convert URL to File or Blob for FileReader.readAsDataURL

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Reference: [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL)

Considering the following example:

```
function previewFile(file) {

  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

It states:

> instanceOfFileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
>
> blob: The Blob or File from which to read.

1. How can a local file URL like: `'file:///C:/path-to/root.png'` be
   passed to the `readAsDataURL()`
2. Is `FileReader()` available in a Firefox Addon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This information is outdated as of now, but cannot be deleted.**

1. You can create [`File` instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code) just by specifying a path when your code is chrome-privileged:

   ```
   new File("/path/to/file");
   ```

   `File` is a sub-class of `Blob`, so all `File` instances are also valid `Blob`s.
   Please note that this requires [a platform path, and not a file URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24844838/484441).
2. Yes, `FileReader` is available to addons.

`File` and `FileReader` are available in all `window`s. If you want to use them in a non-window scope (like `bootstrap.js` or a code module), you may use `nsIDOMFile`/`nsIDOMFileReader`.

Comment: Can you pass the urls returned by `canvas.toDataURL` and `canvas.toBlob` to `new File(here)`?

Comment: @Blagoh No. Why would would you wanna do that anyway? `.toBlob` already returns a blob...

Comment: Oh I was just thinking for non-local url. But for that i can still just do `new File('http://blahblah.png')` right?

Comment: No, not really. For that you can do `XHR` to read (e.g. into an array buffer or directly as text) and then either use the resulting ArrayBuffer or text or just re-wrap if you need a blob for some reason ;)

Comment: How would I do it from a local file URL (not path), like: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/xxx/cache/1445607245908.jpg

Comment: as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File, there ain't any `File()` ctor that simply takes path.

Comment: it is indeed not as simple as that, as File(path) doesn't exist, it's doesn't take only 'path' as argument. It should be something like that instead: [File(bits, path)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: Using the fetch api: `new File([await (await fetch('/path/to/file')).blob()], '/path/to/file')`

Answer (score 84):

To convert a URL to a Blob for FileReader.readAsDataURL() do this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', MY_URL, true);
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
    reader.onload =  function(e){
        console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
    };
};
request.send();
```

Comment: this could really benefit from some elaboration, never defined request.response in the snippet. can responseType or FileReader be used on url's already loaded without making a new XMLHttpRequest(); every time?

Comment: This worked for me. Used the DataURL to load a Raster in paperjs from a image in s3 bucket.

Comment: it seems to work well only on small files. if there is a large mp4 size around 800M, it takes a long time for the browser to respond and play. How could we leverage partial response here?

Comment: not working to me : React Native

Answer (score 71):

Expanding on Felix Turner s response, here is how I would use this approach with the `fetch` API.

```js
async function createFile(){
  let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/test.jpg');
  let data = await response.blob();
  let metadata = {
    type: 'image/jpeg'
  };
  let file = new File([data], "test.jpg", metadata);
  // ... do something with the file or return it
}
createFile();
```

Comment: I'm trying this code for hours, it doesn't work well. We need to change `contentType` to `type`. Thankyou. God bless you!

Comment: Yes this is correct! I have made the edits. Here is a link to the documentation as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: What if you don't know the file extension or content type? Is there a way to extract it from the response fetching?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types (adds a couple hundred KB, but I didn't find an easier way)

Comment: This method return me CORS error. This is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69146764/6678345)

Comment: The CORS error appears to be with getting the blob, not with using the blob to create a File.

Comment: There's something wrong with this method, I get cors error even with everything related to cors allowed.

Answer (score 41):

The suggested edit queue is full for **@tibor-udvari**'s excellent fetch answer, so I'll post my suggested edits as a new answer.

This function gets the content type from the header if returned, otherwise falls back on a settable default type.

```js
async function getFileFromUrl(url, name, defaultType = 'image/jpeg'){
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.blob();
  return new File([data], name, {
    type: data.type || defaultType,
  });
}

// `await` can only be used in an async body, but showing it here for simplicity.
const file = await getFileFromUrl('https://example.com/image.jpg', 'example.jpg');
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this I learned this from @nmaier when I was mucking around with converting to ico:
Well i dont really understand what array buffer is but it does what we need:

```
function previewFile(file) {

  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    console.log(reader.result); //this is an ArrayBuffer
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

notice how i just changed your `readAsDataURL` to `readAsArrayBuffer`.

Here is the example @nmaier gave me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253997/1828637

it has a fiddle

if you want to take this and make a file out of it i would think you would use file-output-stream in the `onloadend`

Comment: Thanks Noitidart. At the moment, I am concentrating on converting it to DataURL I have tested other options but so far the above code (if I get it to work) seems like the cleanest :)

Comment: Can you make a gist at gist.github.com of your final code and share, i would like to see how its done :(

Comment: it is for [iGoogle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/igoogle/) and it will be in the next update.

Comment: @Noitidart what is really happening here flow-wise? We have not passed file to `new FileReader` then how is it reading? `readAsArraysBuffer` getting called before `reader.onload` ?

Comment: Hi @piechuckerr - Now I understand ArrayBuffers very well and DOMFile etc. what is happening above is we are passing a DOMFile and it is being turned into an ArrayBuffer. You can't pass anything else to this function I posted above. What are you trying to do? Load a local file? You can do that from addon scope, and from non-addon scope you will have to give the user a `<input type=browse` and let them browse to it. When the pick it, then it will return a DOMFile which you can pass above. Or if your image is at `http....`, a sin remote, just xhr it with `responseType:arraybuffer`.

Comment: For firefox use `reader.addEventListener("load", () => { ... })`. See [firefox mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#events)

Answer (score 7):

> Here is my code using async awaits and promises

```
const getBlobFromUrl = (myImageUrl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', myImageUrl, true);
        request.responseType = 'blob';
        request.onload = () => {
            resolve(request.response);
        };
        request.onerror = reject;
        request.send();
    })
}

const getDataFromBlob = (myBlob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
    })
}

const convertUrlToImageData = async (myImageUrl) => {
    try {
        let myBlob = await getBlobFromUrl(myImageUrl);
        console.log(myBlob)
        let myImageData = await getDataFromBlob(myBlob);
        console.log(myImageData)
        return myImageData;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return null;
    }
}

export default convertUrlToImageData;
```

Comment: This answer actually returns the original image down to the individual bytes instead of a different image that *looks* the same. If you're trying to implement functionality where you really want the original unaltered image, this is the best answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an expansion off of @tibor-udvari's answer, but for a nicer copy and paste.

```js
async function createFile(url, type){
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return // make sure we are in the browser
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const data = await response.blob()
  const metadata = {
    type: type || 'video/quicktime'
  }
  return new File([data], url, metadata)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wanting something similar to this but without having to pass the type for the file or the filename, so I made my own example based on @Felix Turner's example. I used the `content-disposition` header for the filename first in case the file is coming back from an API endpoint, but use the last part of the URL path if that header doesn't exist.

```js
function getFilenameFromContentDisposition(res) {
  let filename = null;

  const disposition = res.headers.get("content-disposition");

  if (disposition?.includes("attachment")) {
    const filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    const matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
    if (matches?.[1]) {
      filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, "");
      // Sometimes the filename comes in a URI encoded format so decode it
      filename = decodeURIComponent(filename);
      // Sometimes the filename starts with UTF-8, remove that
      filename = filename.replace(/^UTF-8/i, "").trim();
    }
  }

  return filename;
}

async function getFileFromLink(url) {
  const fileRes = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await fileRes.blob();

  let fileName = getFilenameFromContentDisposition(fileRes);
  if (!fileName) {
    fileName = url.split("/").pop();
  }

  const file = new File([blob], fileName, {
    type: blob.type,
  });

  return file;
}
```

If you wanted to make this better, I'd use the [`content-disposition`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-disposition) package on npm for the parsing as the formatting of it can get strange.  I'd also probably use the [`mime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime) package for ensuring that the filename from the URL has a proper file extension based on the returned `content-type`

Answer (score 0):

For my React projects, I use following function I created. It basically gets `imageUrl` as input and returns the `file`. The idea behind is to use `fetch` API and get the image as blob and convert to `File`. For the file name, I just use the original image name using `substring` function.

Important thing is not to forget `try/catch` in your functions.

```
export async function imageUrlToFile(imageUrl) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch image (status ${response.status})`);
        }
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const filename = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const file = new File([blob], filename, { type: blob.type });
        return file;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simplest way to get blob or file object with vanila.js and promise

```
const fileURL_to_blob = (file_url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file_url, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload =  function(e){
            //console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
            resolve(e.target.result);
        };
    };
    request.onerror=function(e){
      reject(e);
    }
    request.send();
  });
}
```