# Using ionic2 to upload image to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, ionic2, firebase-storage

I am using ionic2 beta 11 and firebase 3. I would like to try to upload some image to firebase storage. I have setup a home.ts but I encounter following error :

Error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.

// follow the instruction of https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

public storageRef : any;

constructor () {}

uploadfile(){

var file = "http://imgs.sundaykiss.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/278k_kissfocus09.jpg";

var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + file); 

var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file, metadata);
```

// the editor wanted me the file above, argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.

May I know why ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

put() takes files via the JavaScript [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) APIs
Not a string like you are giving it.
If you don't have the file in byte stream form you'll have to read it from the url into a blob/file.

Comment: Many thanks ! I have tried to read those docs, but I can't make the URL image into blob/file, may you please kindly give an example? Many thanks again !

Comment: A link to an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046301/convert-url-to-file-or-blob-for-filereader-readasdataurl

Answer (score 0):

since you are using a remote url you should be able to use the `fetch` polyfill to get the blob from the image.

`npm module whatwg-fetch`

```
  makeFileIntoBlob(_imagePath) {
    return fetch(_imagePath).then((_response) => {
      return _response.blob();
    }).then((_blob) => {
      return _blob;
    });
  }
```

full example is here [https://github.com/aaronksaunders/firebaseStorage2](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/firebaseStorage2/blob/c33f83a180c92cc690c2c1a1e5d4b48c2fcd1495/app/pages/home/home.ts#L78)

There is also a youtube video showing the whole process [Ionic2 Firebase Image Upload](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yGrLWq-oIo)