# Load m3u8 video file as Blob with different orign

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js, m3u8

I'm attempting to stream video using a Blob URL created from an m3u8 URL.

The m3u8 file contains only relative paths.

E.g.

```
file1.ts
file2.ts
...
```

The m3u8 file is stored on a separate host (e.g. the URL is fileserver.com/path/thevideo.m3u8) than the website loading the video (e.g. the URL is website.com).

Therefore, after converting the m3u8 URL to a Blob, the video player subsequently looks for:

```
website.com/file1.ts
website.com/file2.ts
```

Whereas, the actual URLs are:

```
fileserver.com/path/file1.ts
fileserver.com/path/file2.ts
```

Question is, is there any way to get the video player (I'm using VideoJS) to use the correct URL prefix?

The code I used for Blob URL generation is here: [set video objects source file to a blob url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184900/set-video-objects-source-file-to-a-blob-url)

I can confirm that it works if the m3u8 file contains the full *.ts URLs instead of the relative paths, but I want to see if this is possible using only the relative path as that would be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a custom handler for requests made by [videojs/http-streaming](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) engine.

```
player.tech().vhs.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options) {
  options.uri = options.uri.replace('example.com', 'foo.com');

  return options;
};
```

Note: You should make a check with safari hls playback if you're using `overrideNative` option.