# How to block opening a video blob url in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, blob, block

I created a page with an HTML5 video player and a blob url and I blocked access to the download button everything works fine but I have a problem when I retrieve the blob url by looking at the code of the page and that I paste the blob url in a new tab I can watch the video in player with the download button.

url of my script to generate the blob url : [set video objects source file to a blob url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184900/set-video-objects-source-file-to-a-blob-url)

So question: How to prevent the opening of the video in a new tab via its url blob ?

Answer (score 0):

That blob url is the source of video so you cannot prevent to access video while there is access to its source.

[prevent html5 video from being downloaded right click saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved#answer-9756909)

Comment: Yes but no ! If I asked this question it is because I tried the same thing (opening a blob url in a new tab) on another site example porn site Lol and I do not have access to the video new tab equals error!
According to my research it is a story of ID or Time or both.
I don't know how to apply this but apparently my blob url should be like this: blob: https: //www.mysite.com/b4779572-0ecd-47a2-83c5-46033dc90526? Id = 54321987

Comment: Maybe it split video into multiple chunks or something so opening splitted part cause error. This answer presents few solutions and useful links for start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved#answer-9756909