# Give a bits parameter of the File object using Ionic 3 file url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this base64 conversion method. It expects `file` and type as `Blob`. But I have file path for the pdf file. e.g.: `let filePath: string = 'file:///...my.pdf';`. So how can I consume below method then?

```
 getBase64(file: Blob) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }
```

I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046554/1077309). But it expects more than what the dev mentioned.

i.e. `new File("/path/to/file");`. This is simpley not work. It expects like this `File(bits, name [, options]);`. But how can I give `bits` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need the above method since [native file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) does the job for me.i.e. it returns the `base64` string.

```
let base64String = await this.file.readAsDataURL(pdfFilePath, pdfFilename)
```